# Awk: Match data in 2 files with duplicate keys

Tags: perl, awk

I have 2 files
file1

```
a^b=-123
a^3=-124
c^b=-129
a^b=-130
```

and file2

```
a^b=-523
a^3=-524
a^b=-530
```

I want to lookup the key using '=' as delimiter and get the following output

```
a^b^-123^-523
a^b^-130^-530
a^3^-124^-524
```

When there were no duplicate keys, it was easy to do it in awk mapping the first file and looping over the second, however, with the duplicates, its slightly difficult. I tried something like this:

```
awk -F"=" '
   FNR == NR {
      arr[$1 "^" $2] = $2;
      next;
   }
   FNR < NR {
      for (i in arr) {
         match(i, , /^(.*\^.*)\^([-0-9]*)$/, , ar);
         if ($1 == ar[1]) {
            if ($2 in load == 0) {
               if (ar[2] in l2 == 0) {
                  l2[ar[2]] = ar[2];
                  load[$2] = $2;
                  print i "^" $2
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
' file1 file2
```

This works just fine, however, not surprisingly it's extremely slow. On a file with about 600K records, it ran for 4 hours.

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this in one line awk or perl. If possible, a one liner would be great help.

thanks.

Comment: The key `a^b` appears twice in each input file, which means there are four possible output combinations that could be generated: `a^b=-123=-523`, `a^b=-123=-530`, `a^b=-130=-523`, and `a^b=-130=-150`.  Which ones do you want, and why?

Comment: @Dale, it can have `a^b=-123=-523` and `a^b=-130=-523` or `a^b=-123=-530` and `a^b=-130=-150`. The id combinations don't matter, as long as the pairs are unique for the keys.

Comment: I was attempting to find out why the standard `join` output isn't right for you.  Unfortunately, it's still not quite clear why to me, but if you find the enhanced `join` approach appropriate, it's not that important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the `join` command which does something very much like you're doing here, but generates a full database-style join.  For example, assuming `file1` and `file2` contain the data you show above, then the commands

```
$ sort -o file1.out -t = -k 1,1 file1
$ sort -o file2.out -t = -k 1,1 file2
$ join -t = file1.out file2.out
```

produces the output

```
a^3=-124=-524
a^b=-123=-523
a^b=-123=-530
a^b=-130=-523
a^b=-130=-530
```

The sorts are necessary because, to be efficient, `join` requires the input file to be sorted on the keys being compared.  Note though that this generates the full cross-product join, which appears not to be what you want.

(**Note:** The following is a very shell-heavy solution, but you could cast it fairly easily into any programming language with dynamic arrays and a built-in sort primitive.  Unfortunately, awk isn't one of those but perl and python are, as are I'm sure just about every newer scripting language.)

It seems that you really want each instance of a key to be *consumed* the first time it's emitted in any output.  You can get this as follows, again starting with the original contents of `file1` and `file2`.

```
$ nl -s = -n rz file1 | sort -t = -k 2,2 > file1.out
$ nl -s = -n rz file2 | sort -t = -k 2,2 > file2.out
```

This decorates each line with the original line number so that we can recover the original order later, and then sorts them on the key for join.  The remainder of the work is a short pipeline, which I've broken up into multiple blocks so it can be explained as we go.

```
join -t = -1 2 -2 2 file1.out file2.out |
```

This command joins on the key names, now in field two, and emits records like those shown from the earlier output of join, except that each line now includes the line number where the key was found in file1 and file2.  Next, we want to re-establish the search order your original algorithm would have used, so we continue the pipeline with

```
 sort -t = -k 2,2 -k 4,4 |
```

which sorts first on the file1 line number and then on the file2 line numbers.  Finally, we need to efficiently emulate the assumption that a particular key, once consumed, cannot be re-used, in order to eliminate the unwanted matches in the original join output.

```
awk '
   BEGIN { OFS="="; FS="=" }
   $2 in seen2 || $4 in seen4 { next }
   { seen2[$2]++; seen4[$4]++; print $1,$3,$5 }
'
```

This ignores every line that references a previously scanned key in either file, and otherwise prints the following

```
a^b=-123=-523
a^3=-124=-524
a^b=-130=-530
```

This should be uniformly efficient even for quite large inputs, because the sorts are *O(n log n)*, and everything else is *O(n)*.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the solution with line number. Neat idea. I did try the usual `join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` but like you mentioned, it produces all the combinations.

Comment: The technique is hardly original with me: it's a long-standing bit of folklore that might not get written down explicitly very often.  Essentially, sometimes sorting is very useful, but loses some other important ordering property you'll need later.  In that case, decorate the records to be sorted with a new value remembering the original order, apply the sort you need, do whatever operation is now more efficient, and then re-sort to get back the order you wanted.  The `perl` folks call this the _Schwarzian Transform_, after Randall Schwarz, but it pre-dates `perl` as well.

Comment: the code worked very well and gave me the desired output. Thank you so much for explaining the approach and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this awk codes, see if it would be faster than yours: (it could be an one-liner, if you join all lines, but I think with formatting, it is easier to read)

```
awk -F'=' -v OFS="^" 'NR==FNR{sub(/=/,"^");a[NR]=$0;t=NR;next}
{   s=$1
        sub(/\^/,"\\^",s)
        for(i=1;i<=t;i++){
                if(a[i]~s){
                        print  a[i],$2
                        delete a[i]
                        break
                        }
                }
        }' file1 file2
```

with your example, it outputs expected result:

```
a^b^-123^-523
a^3^-124^-524
a^b^-130^-530
```

But I think the key is performance here. so give it a try.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and I'll let you know how it goes. this looks promising.

Comment: this approach was certainly faster than mine, but it still took over an hour on 2 files with 600K rows. @Dale's solution worked and took about a minute.